# Why didn't King Shlomo get lashes for marrying more than 18 wives?

Tags: mitzvah, maseches-sanhedrin, king-solomon, polygamy

It [states](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/seferHamitzvos.asp?tdate=8/28/2018) in the 364th prohibition that a king is forbidden from having too many wives.

> The limit is that he may not have more than 18 wives legally bound by
>   kesubah and kiddushin.
>
> The details of this mitzvah are explained in the second chapter of
>   tractate Sanhedrin. Whenever he adds on to this limit, he is punished
>   by lashes.

Was Shlomo Hamelech lashed for taking more than 18 wives, and if not, why not?

Comment: For the same reason nobody told Stalin it was wrong to have so many people executed.

Comment: note that you'd need an acceptance of hasrah, and Chazal tell us that he had a rational why it was permitted to do as he did, in which case it is to be assumed he wouldn't accept hasroh.

Comment: Orangeandlemons, would you  kindly give me a source for what you wrote re hasroh?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/136588

Answer (score -2):

The answer is very simple, as the [Gemmorah in Sanhedrin 21a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.21a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) puts it - **it is a Machlokes: any number from 18 to unlimited can be accepted** based on different approaches by different Rabbis.

---

*NB: Always keep in mind that though we have a tradition that previous generations kept rulings of the later (as you imply in your question) it does not hold empirically. This Halacha was not ruled clearly up until the Rishonim (Rambam)*

Comment: Okay, so you’re just pushing off the question. According to the Tanna Kamma who poses a hard limit and according to R’ Shimon who says even one is forbidden if she turns him away, why didn’t Shlomo HaMelech get lashes? You’re just answering “We now pasken like the Tanna Kamma - maybe back then they paskened like R’ Yehudah.” Then Shlomo should be a disproof against all other opinions!

Answer (score -2):

This is not the only occasion where a potential Chayav Malkus prohibition might have been transgressed but yet the Tenach chooses not to go into details of anyone's private life when its not relevant for future generations as it says in Masechet Megila 14a:

> תניא הרבה נביאים עמדו להם לישראל כפלים כיוצאי מצרים אלא נבואה שהוצרכה לדורות נכתבה ושלא הוצרכה לא נכתבה

If Eidim gave Him warning then testified against him he would have gotten punished sanhedrin 19a

> מלכי בית דוד דן ודנין אותן דכתיב (ירמיהו כא, יב) בית דוד כה אמר ה' דינו לבקר משפט

But there is nowhere that mentions if there was hasraa (warning) and that he was therefore liable to malkus so we will never know what really happened and it is not relevant

Comment: The question asked if he got lashes. Are you answering “he did, but it doesn’t say so” or “it doesn’t matter, because we’d know if it did matter”? If it’s the former, how do you know that he did? If it’s the latter, there are plenty of things in this vein which Gemaras and Midrashim tell us that aren’t in the passuk explicitly.

Comment: @donielf if eidim gave Him warning then testified against him he would have gotten punished sanhedrin 19a מלכי בית דוד דן ודנין אותן דכתיב (ירמיהו כא, יב) בית דוד כה אמר ה' דינו לבקר משפט but there is nowhere that mentions if there was hasraa and malkus this because it is not relevent

Comment: Let me ask you something. What was Avraham’s mother’s name? “The passuk doesn’t tell us, it’s not relevant, who cares?” Well, her name happens to be אמתלאי בת כרנבו (Bava Basra 91a). Things come up in Midrashim that aren’t important enough to be in the pesukim.

Comment: @DonielF you can ask a seperate question "what did shlomo eat for breakfast on the wednesday? if he ate pig did they lash him" and many more claiming they might be somewhere in a midrash., i understand you don't want to reverse your negative vote, maybe let the questioner daniel  bilar see if this answers his question but i think our conversation is over for now

Comment: (That one is actually answered in Melachim Aleph 5:2-3.) I disagree with any answer claiming that a question is a stupid question, provided that the question gives some motivation. I was in your shoes on a recent question regarding the length of Moshe’s staff, because it didn’t demonstrate why anyone should care. Here that’s been demonstrated, and as such, deserves a proper answer.

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/965/9682